# while running Hyperldger Query from multi user rest server It gives error "Invalid or extraneous parameter access_token has been specified"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using a multi user rest server with ldap based authentication on. I can successfully login , get an access token and perform any number of transactions. Chaincode running for this transaction can also run the queries generate by me. But the issue is I am not able t run this queries directly from my Web browser while using same access token. I am facing this error which says that access_token is invalid or extraneous parameter while running query. But when I try to run query without access token it gives me error as "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED" Which as per my understanding is okay. Also this queries are running fine in single user rest server.

Do i need to perform something different while running queries using multi user rest server with access token generated from LDAP.

> "{"error":{"statusCode":500,"name":"Error","message":"2 UNKNOWN: error
>   executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: ***Invalid
>   or extraneous parameter access_token has been***
>   specified","code":2,"metadata":{"_internal_repr":{}},"details":"error
>   executing chaincode: transaction returned with failure: Error: Invalid
>   or extraneous parameter access_token has been
>   specified","stack":"Error: 2 UNKNOWN: error executing chaincode:
>   transaction returned with failure: Error: Invalid or extraneous
>   parameter access_token has been specified\n    at new
>   createStatusError
>   (/home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)\n    at
>   /home/composer/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:583:15"}}"

Comment: Can you clarify: After successful auth, you say you CAN submit transactions via REST APIs - but you CAN'T call REST API queries in the same business network / using the same business network card? Can you provide screenshots for both?

Comment: Actually We have made some changes to make it work actually issue is with the way we were passing the access token. In hyperledger Documents there are 2 ways through which we can pass token :
1. curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping?access_token=xxxxx

Comment: Actually We have made some changes to make it work actually issue is with the way we were passing the access token. In hyperledger Documents there are 2 ways through which we can pass token :
1. curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping?access_token=xxxxx
2. curl -v -H 'X-Access-Token: xxxxx' http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping

But only 2nd one works fine with query.

Answer (score 0):

Actually We have made some changes to make it work actually issue is with the way we were passing the access token. In hyperledger Documents there are 2 ways through which we can pass token :

> 1. curl -v http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping?access_token=xxxxx
> 2. curl -v -H 'X-Access-Token: xxxxx' http://localhost:3000/api/system/ping

I was using the 1st method to pass access token and all my transactions were working fine but query failed seems access token was passed on to query and it was not able to identify parameter. So I tried second way and was able to run the query. **I Suppose Hyperleder forums should mention such limitations.**